# Infinite loop exception

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to generate an exception for an infinite loop while folding a map.

```
module X=Map.Make(Int)
```

The problem goes like this: Determine the max rank for which the function "f" doesn't lead into an infinite loop. We have a map `[(1,2);(2,3);(5,6);(6,7);(7,6)]`

The function goes through all the pairs of the map like this:

for the first pair (1,2) => f(1)=2 Now I'll try f(2) = 3 (As it exists in the pair (2,3)) now I'll try f(3) => Cannot find any key = 3 so the rank is the number of times I could call the function f, in this case, it's 2.

for the pair (5,6) => f(5)=6 I'll try f(6) = 7 (the pair (6,7) exists) I'll try f(7) = 6 (The pair (7,6) exists) I'll try f(6) = 7 goes into a loop, because I have already used the pair (6,7) once, so the rank in this case is 0;

Conclusion: The max rank of the function f if it does not go into an infinite loop is 2.

How can I define my exception, as well as what reasoning can I use to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time to understand the task... it basically resembles me the rules of the [World Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_chain) game. A more scientific description would be: find the length of a [simple path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)), starting from the given node.

> How can I define my exception

This is simple:

```
exception Loop_detected
```

> what reasoning can I use to solve the problem

The easiest way to detect a loop would be to maintain a set of all visited nodes. As soon, as you hit a node, that you have already seen, you should bail out with `Loop_detected` exception, e.g., `if Ints.mem dst visited then raise Loop_detected`. You can create an `Ints` set module for `int`s with the following definition:

```
 module Ints = Set.Make(Int)
```

Using a set of all visited nodes is a common but not the only way of detecting loops. You can use a [Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm for this. It is also described more formally in Stepanov's Elements of Programming book, in the [Transformations and their Orbits](http://elementsofprogramming.com/032163537X_Sample.pdf) chapter, that is available online.

Comment: The "two racing cars" approach is best known as  Floyd's *Tortoise and the Hare* algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare.

Comment: yeah, I was striving to recall it, but my memory has taken an absence day)) Thanks, will update the post.